# channel form not working on index

Tags: channel-form

this is my form:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="contactform" return="contact/dank" include_jquery="no"  include_assets="no"}
<div class="span6">
    <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33"  name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Surname">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Company">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="function" id="function" placeholder="Function">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip code">
        </div>
</div>
<div class="span6 last notopspace">
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="country" id="country" placeholder="Country">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        </div>
        <div class="field mandatory">
            <input type="text" class="text-input mandatory" size="33" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Tel">
        </div>
</div>                                      
<div class="span12">
            <textarea cols="78" rows="5" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Insert free text"></textarea>
            <div class="actionbuttons">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" id="formsubmit">
            </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:form}
```

CHANNEL FORM SETTINGS:
contactform> allow guest posts: Yes

i include the form as a snippet and i had to disable jquery as it gave conflicts.

the forms works via /home or /contact, but not via index

Comment: Can you post the entire contents between the `exp:channel:form` tags? Typically `return` parameters take a `tmpl_group/tmpl_name` value.

Comment: as siebird says, have you tried ```return="news/index"```

Comment: @Gdmac yes, tried that, tmpl_group/tmpl_name doesn't makes a difference

Comment: the first link you gave works for me, "msg sent".

Comment: @gdmac was testing, as email form it works, not with exp:channel:form

Comment: I tested it locally and it works fine for me in a test/index template. Try with a most simple form and expand from there. Also seems you have EE in a subdirectory, have you set site-index and site-url correctly under admin-general settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the action on the form points to 
http://syntetik.be/artilium-ee instead of
http://syntetik.be/artilium-ee/ like the url